# retrofit2 отправить Bitmap на сервер

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Есть Bitmap (Именно битмап или дальнейшее его преобразование) объект. Каким образом можно отправить его на сервер? Сам в изучении навичек.

Comment: Какой сервер? Протокол?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець простой сервер по http протоколы в Post запросе

Comment: Кладите ваш объект в атрибут или параметр и делайте `post`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець какой должен быть тип аргумента?

Comment: `public void setAttribute(String name, Object object);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp;    
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmp.recycle();

RequestBody body = createRequestBody("application/octet-stream", byteArray);

@POST
Call<ResponseBody> post(@Body RequestBody body, 
                        @Url String url);
```